# Calculating size of array to calculate the average using threads

Tags: c, multithreading, size, average

I have this huge header file `average.h` which contains 4 arrays. I want to calculate the average of the header file by calculating the average of the 4 arrays separately using threads. 
I'm getting a segmentation fault when running, so I guess there is something wrong with how I calculate the length of the array. I've been told that it's impossible to calculate the size of a `float**` so how should I go about this then?

Here is my code:

```
/*
 * File:   main.c
 * Author: thomasvanhelden
 *
 * Created on June 15, 2014, 5:34 AM
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "average.h"

void* calc(void* param) {
    float** array = (float**) param;
    int size = sizeof(*array) / sizeof(float*);
    int i;
    float sum = 0;
    float* average;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sum += *array[i];
    }

    *average = sum/size;

    return average;
}

/*
 *
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    pthread_t t1, t2, t3, t4;   // thread handlers
    int res1, res2, res3, res4; // results of creating/joining the threads
    void *avg1, *avg2, *avg3, *avg4; // results of the threads as void*
    float *result1, *result2, *result3, *result4;   // results of the threads as flaot*

    // create the threads
    res1 = pthread_create(&t1, NULL, calc, a1);
    res2 = pthread_create(&t2, NULL, calc, a2);
    res3 = pthread_create(&t3, NULL, calc, a3);
    res4 = pthread_create(&t4, NULL, calc, a4);

    // check for errors creating the threads
    if (res1 || res2 || res3 || res4) {
        printf("Something went wrong creating the threads!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // wait for the threads to finish and get the result
    res1 = pthread_join(t1, &avg1);
    res2 = pthread_join(t2, &avg2);
    res3 = pthread_join(t3, &avg3);
    res4 = pthread_join(t4, &avg4);

    // check for errors joining the threads
    if (res1 || res2 || res3 || res4) {
        printf("Something went wrong joining the threads!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // void* to float*
    result1 = (float*) avg1;
    result2 = (float*) avg2;
    result3 = (float*) avg3;
    result4 = (float*) avg4;

    // print the result, should be
    printf("The average is: %f", (*result1 + *result2 + *result3 + *result4));


    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Show the declarations of the arrays.

Comment: Is this working? I believe below statement will give you 1 always as the size of pointer is always 4 bytes on a 32 bit platform: int size = sizeof(* array) / sizeof(float *);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, it is impossible to retrieve the size of your array from a pointer. You must pack your parameters in a struct (your `float**`, plus the size of your array, and any other relevant information), and pass a pointer to this stucture to `pthread_create()`.

Note that your worker function must return a pointer, hence the need to allocate memory. If you wish to avoid dynamic allocation, here is a pattern reusing the parameter struct as a return value too :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define ARRAY_COUNT(arr) (sizeof (arr) / sizeof *(arr))

typedef union {
    struct {    // Function parameters
        float *array;
        size_t size;
    };
    struct {    // Function return value
        float result;
    };
} arrayAverageParam_u;

void *arrayAverage(void *param) {
    arrayAverageParam_u *_param = param;
    // From now on we can use _param to access the struct

    int i;
    float avg = 0.0f;
    for(i = 0; i < _param->size; ++i)
        avg += _param->array[i];

    if(i)
        avg /= i;

    // Store the result, overwriting the parameters
    _param->result = avg;

    return NULL;
}

main()
{
    float array[] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f};

    // Fill the struct with parameters
    arrayAverageParam_u param = {
        .array = array,
        .size = ARRAY_COUNT(array),
    };

    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, arrayAverage, &param);

    pthread_join(thread, NULL);

    // Retrieve the result from the struct
    printf("The average is %g\n", param.result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a great idea! I was thinking of hardcoding the size of the array into the for-loop, but yours sounds a lot better. Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to accept this answer if it suits the problem :)

Comment: Sorry about that, I did it now. Thought I had to wait a few hours in order to be able to accept answers... :/

Comment: No problem at all, glad to have helped :)